# Looking for story about farmer who sees aliens land in his field, but it turns out that the farmer is the alien and the aliens are humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for the name of a YA Science Fiction short story that I read in middle school in the 70’s. As I remember it, the story was told from the perspective of a farmer who was tending his fields one day when he sees an alien space craft land in his field. The aliens that emerge are horrendous and disgust and frighten him. As a result he flees as fast as he can. However in the description of his fleeing, it is revealed that the scene takes place on another world and it is in fact the farmer who is the alien. Humans have landed on this extraterrestrial world.

Comment: It's a similar plot to [The Invaders (The Twilight Zone, S2E15, 1961) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invaders_(The_Twilight_Zone)). Or watch ["Reader's Digest" version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n99iNW9595o).

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of "Youth" by Isaac Asimov which you can read here: https://archive.org/stream/Space_Science_Fiction_v01n01_1952-05_cape1736#page/n68/mode/1up

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but neither Youth or the Invaders hits the mark. I wish I could provide more plot details, but it’s just been too long.